# Html.Action from a partial view

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Im callning Html.Action from a partial view in a asp.net Mvc application. The call is made to a void method that is supposed to receive the model object comming in to the partial view but the method receives null.

Model comming in to partial view:

```
@model IEnumerable<RA.Web.Models.BookedResource>
```

Html.Action:

```
@Html.Action("SendEmailConfirmation", "BookedResource", Model.ToList())
```

The void method that receives null in bookedResources:

```
public void SendEmailConfirmation(List<BookedResource> bookedResources)
{
    var email = new Email();
    email.SendEMail(CurrentUser, "Subject",     CreateBodyForConfirmation(bookedResources)); 
}
```

Anybody knows why the parameter is null?

Comment: Can you post the code for `BookedResource`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Html.Action` has an overload that expects route values as an object, but not `List<Object>`. You can create a `ViewModel`Instead of using `List<BookedResource>`. See below:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
     public List<BookedResource> BookedResources { get; set; }
}
```

Then use MyViewModel in your view:

```
   @model MyViewModel 

   @Html.Action("SendEmailConfirmation", "BookedResource", Model)
```

finally use MyViewModel as the parameter type:

```
public void SendEmailConfirmation(MyViewModel bookedResources)
{
    //
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Html.Action() takes route values, not a model.

You might be better off with a jquery ajax call back to your controller action. I've never really seen Html.Action used this way anyway. It is intended to return html.